# Connecting Database from VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

How to connect and retrieve whole table from sql server and mysql, how to establish the Connection. I can able to connect it Ms Access and retrieve the table, but am facing tough time to find out easy and reliable solution. I have atted my Ms access connnection. Please help out in connecting with other Database tools.

```
Public Function Connect_To_AccessDB(strDBPath As String) As DAO.Database
Dim objAccess As Access.Application
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set objAccess = New Access.Application
Set db = objAccess.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDBPath, False, False)
Set Connect_To_AccessDB = db
```

End Function

Private Sub Connect_To_AccessDB_Example()
    Dim AccessDB As DAO.Database

```
'Example to assign a database to a variable
Set AccessDB = Connect_To_AccessDB("c:\temp\TestDB.accdb")

AccessDB.Execute ("create table tbl_test3 (num number,firstname char, lastname char)")


AccessDB.Close
Set AccessDB = Nothing

'Example to delete an external database file (.accdb)
'Kill ("c:\temp\TestDB.accdb")

'Example to close Access
'DoCmd.Quit
```

End Sub

Comment: [This](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) might help

Comment: For other databases you want to use ADO, not DAO.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/ado-code-examples-vbscript?view=sql-server-ver15